# FFMPEG scale and crop in single command

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG on Android using the following lib: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

This is the command I'm using:

```
"-i " + path + " -vf scale=480:360,crop=360:360:0:00 -strict -2  -preset ultrafast " + fileOutPath
```

My goal of this is to scale the image down to 480x360, then crop it to 360x360 from (0,0) (top left corner). HOWEVER, what ends up happening is that it crops from the vertical-center. So for example if you were to take a vide of three blocks on top of each other filling the entire screen, the crop would eventually show just the middle block, whereas I desire the top block.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

My ultimate goal from all of this is to get a square video of size 360x360.

Output log:

```html
03-26 12:10:16.816 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onStart
03-26 12:10:16.900 17198-17385/com.noq D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
03-26 12:10:16.914 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.noq/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
03-26 12:10:17.004 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
03-26 12:10:17.004 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
03-26 12:10:17.007 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
03-26 12:10:17.021 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
03-26 12:10:17.022 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.noq/files/Pictures/noq/1459008610063.mp4':
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     major_brand     : mp42
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     compatible_brands: isommp42
03-26 12:10:17.201 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:02.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6131 kb/s
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 5926 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 4:3, 29.87 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       rotate          : 270
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       encoder         : MOTO
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Side data:
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
03-26 12:10:17.202 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
03-26 12:10:17.263 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] using SAR=1/1
03-26 12:10:17.297 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] using cpu capabilities: none!
03-26 12:10:17.411 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.1
03-26 12:10:17.417 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.noq/files/Pictures/noq/14590086100631459008616802_square.mp4':
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     major_brand     : mp42
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     compatible_brands: isommp42
03-26 12:10:17.464 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 360x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 30.17 fps, 11584 tbn, 30.17 tbc (default)
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       rotate          : 270
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
03-26 12:10:17.465 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
03-26 12:10:17.466 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:     Metadata:
03-26 12:10:17.466 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
03-26 12:10:17.466 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
03-26 12:10:17.467 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
03-26 12:10:17.467 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: Stream mapping:
03-26 12:10:17.467 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
03-26 12:10:17.467 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
03-26 12:10:17.468 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
03-26 12:10:18.035 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
03-26 12:10:18.526 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: frame=   21 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=      48kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 390.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
03-26 12:10:19.008 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: frame=   26 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=      68kB time=00:00:01.85 bitrate= 301.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
03-26 12:10:19.533 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: frame=   47 fps= 23 q=23.0 size=     165kB time=00:00:01.87 bitrate= 719.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
03-26 12:10:19.956 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: frame=   62 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=     297kB time=00:00:02.05 bitrate=1184.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
03-26 12:10:19.956 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: video:262kB audio:33kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.992648%
03-26 12:10:19.984 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size: 18507
03-26 12:10:19.984 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] frame P:61    Avg QP:23.52  size:  4079
03-26 12:10:19.984 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
03-26 12:10:19.984 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] mb P  I16..4:  4.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 70.9%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.7%
03-26 12:10:19.985 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.6% 40.1% 14.8% inter: 39.1% 32.7% 0.6%
03-26 12:10:19.985 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] i16 v,h,dc,p: 42% 24% 21% 13%
03-26 12:10:19.986 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 24% 25%  8%
03-26 12:10:19.987 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] kb/s:1040.60
03-26 12:10:20.002 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onSuccess: WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.noq/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                                                 ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
                                                   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
                                                   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
                                                   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
                                                   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
                                                   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
                                                   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
                                                   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
                                                   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
                                                 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.noq/files/Pictures/noq/1459008610063.mp4':
                                                   Metadata:
                                                     major_brand     : mp42
                                                     minor_version   : 0
                                                     compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                     creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
                                                   Duration: 00:00:02.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6131 kb/s
                                                     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 5926 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 4:3, 29.87 fps, 30.17 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                     Metadata:
                                                       rotate          : 270
                                                       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
                                                       handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                       encoder         : MOTO
                                                     Side data:
                                                       displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
                                                     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
                                                     Metadata:
                                                       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
                                                       handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                 [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] using SAR=1/1
                                                 [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] using cpu capabilities: none!
                                                 [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.1
                                                 [libx264 @ 0xb78cde30] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
                                                 Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.noq/files/Pictures/noq/14590086100631459008616802_square.mp4':
                                                   Metadata:
                                                     major_brand     : mp42
                                                     minor_version   : 0
                                                     compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
                                                     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 360x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 30.17 fps, 11584 tbn, 30.17 tbc (default)
                                                     Metadata:
                                                       rotate          : 270
                                                       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
                                                       handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
                                                     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
                                                     Metadata:
                                                       creation_time   : 2016-03-26 16:10:16
                                                       handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                       encoder         : La
03-26 12:10:20.037 17198-17198/com.noq D/FFMPEG: FFMPEG onFinish
```

Comment: Should work as expected.

Comment: @Mulvya...should, but doesn't :)

Comment: Do just the crop and see if the behaviour's the same.

Comment: @Mulvya if I only do the crop, it takes a 360x360 crop from the original video feed, which is not what I need. It has to be scaled. I basically need the entire width of the original video, not a portion.

Comment: Yeah, but check if it takes from the top-left or centre.

Comment: Show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I added the logs! Thanks for looking into this, I was hoping you would see my post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your source video is rotated 90!

To use, with original pixel matrix

```
-vf scale=480:360,crop=360:360:120:0
```

With rotation reset, with ffmpeg versions from May 2015 or later.

```
"-noautorotate -i " + path + \
" -vf scale=480:360,transpose=2,crop=360:360:0:0 
 -strict -2 -preset ultrafast -metadata:s:v rotate=0" + fileOutPath
```

For older versions, skip the noautorotate flag.

Comment: No it's not :/ what makes you say so?

Comment: This: "displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees"

Comment: I was hoping you were right :( this just stretched my video horizontally

Comment: @Mulvya I believe 2.4.2 is too old for automatic rotation and the `-noautorotate` option.

Comment: Updated. My first command assumes that older versions don't reset the rotation tag.